# Can we get chat.security.stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, chat

It's so much easier than http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/it-security and I know some other Beta sites have similar addresses for their room indexes.  Can we, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Iszi, they don't anymore.
SE removed the chat subdomains a while back, no more chat-per-site.
However there is a chat room for ITSec - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151 (but you already knew that :) ).

Comment: And, for all rooms, http://chat.stackexchange.com/?host=security.stackexchange.com.